# Mysterious behavior with pySerial

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I got the following problem:

I have a Arduino here which is connected to my Mac.
The Arduino is reading and responding to serial data.
I made a little python3-script which takes user input and uses
pySerial to write commands like 'set(13, 255)~' to the Arduino.
That is just working fine:

```
while 1:

cmd = input("<<< ")
cmd += '~'

if cmd != "~":
    serialPort.write(cmd.encode())

    output = str(serialPort.readline()).upper()[2:-5]

    if output != " ":
        print(">>> ", output)
```

Here's the Problem:

If I want to send some "automated" commands within the script, e.g. in a loop, the Arduino is not responding anymore, even the commands send are
the same, also encoded and of type "byte".

```
for i in range[0, 256]:

    cmd = 'set(13, '
    cmd += str(i)
    cmd += ')~'

    serialPort.write(cmd.encode())

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The strange thing is, if i first declare the variable (cmd) as an input, its also working fine, but that means a manual interrupt every time the command is send.

```
cmd = input()

cmd = 'set(13, '
cmd += str(i)
cmd += ')~'
```

After some hours of research i absolutely have no idea what the problem might be. As I said, the datatype is always byte after encoding.

Comment: try add a serialPort.flush after the write call

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PySerial, but I suspect it's because the write call don't send the data immediately.

When you use the input, it will add a newline to the buffer, which may trigger the write call to flush automatically.

In the other piece of code you have, you don't add a newline to the buffer and it won't flush the data, before the buffer is big enough.
So with a flush() call it should force send it.

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just had to make a longer interrupt after connecting to the port.
(Has not been a problem since I had to give some input so far)